# XML element with an index?

Tags: xml

What I want to do is basically have my XML look like this:

```
<root>
  <Map1>  </Map1>
  <Map2>  </Map2> 
  <Map3>  </Map3>
</root>
```

I don't want to have to declare a new variable every time I want a new map, so how would I create an index at the end of my variable?

Comment: Why do you need an index in the first place ? What's it about variables ? Something tells me there's more to this question than just xml. You can always have an "id" tag inside "Map".

Comment: Just to make it easier to add and retrieve information? I may be over complicating things.

Comment: There is no such thing as *abstract information*.  What is your problem domain?  What are you trying to save?

Comment: Just wanting to store numbers which will be read in to generate a map for a game.

Comment: callum you're missing the whole point of XML which is to standardize data structure so that your tags are consistent and you can easily read it. Adding an index just so you can "iterate" is missing the point. There are XML parsers for most if not all programming languages if that is where you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an index attribute, so your xml becomes:

```
<root>
  <Map index="1" />
  <Map index="2" />
  <Map index="3" />
</root>
```